# An Encoder-Decoder based CNN to predict a tensor of points

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, python, computer-vision

So I have with me a data of rendered 2D images of a 3D object and along with that, I have the image projection coordinates `(X, Y)` of all the voxels that are in the camera perspective in that image.

The rendered image[image]

The voxel camera projections(This is just for visualization purposes)
[image]

I wanted to build a CNN which takes an input a rendered image and outputs all the voxel camera projection coordinates `(X, Y)`.I was thinking to try out an encoder-decoder based network (like a `U-Net`) but shouldn't the image obtained after decoding be the same dimensions as the input image. I want my decoder to output the tensor of coordinates but I am having a hard time thinking about how it would do so.